# positive voltage from non-inverting amplifier is cut off

Tags: simulation, kicad, pspice

I'm experimenting with simulations in Kicad and have weird behaving output voltage and input current. R2 is being tuned in the simulation window to 2k. I'm using TL082 as the subcircuit for the opamp.

[image: circuit]

[image: graph]

why is the voltage being cut off? Why is the input current in spikes?

Comment: What are you positive and negative supply rails connected to in terms of supply voltages?

Comment: VDD is 7v, VEE is -7V

Comment: So after inspecting VDD and VEE i see that they are also sinusoidal waves, but i have set them to a DC value.

Comment: And what happens now?

Comment: i dont understand why  vdd and vee are sinusoidal because i have them set to dc values.

Comment: Maybe you have also set their output impedance to be non-zero?

Answer (score 0):

So the mistake was that the VCC and VEE symbols don't work as expected and you need to have a voltage source instead, like so:

[image]

Comment: VEE, VDD and GND are just power symbols (basically the same thing as your VIN and VOUT labels but with graphics). There are simply global labels (or cross references). In other words they only define a net name not any other functionality. For more complex circuits you might still want to use these labels and have your true sources connected to the labels instead of the pins.